# Heap corruption while trying to sort an array

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool wayToSort(int i, int j) { return i > j; }
bool wayToSortAlt(int i, int j) { return i < j; }

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int size = 5;
    int *myArray = new int[size] { 0 };
    int option = 0;

    cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter?: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "How do you want to sort? ( [1] Greatest [2] Lowest ): ";
    cin >> option;
    cout << "----\n";

    // Get number inputs
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> myArray[count];
    }

    cout << "----\nSorted:\n----\n";

    // Sort for highest numbers
    if (option == 1)
        sort(myArray, myArray + size, wayToSort);
    else
        sort(myArray, myArray + size, wayToSortAlt);

    // Print each number
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    {
        cout << myArray[count] << "\n";
    }

    delete[] myArray;   // Clean up
    myArray = nullptr;  //

    return 0;
}
```

I run this code in Visual Community 2013 and if I input a high number such as 10, I get a heap corruption error. From what I have read, the heap corruption error happens when you try to write to an unallocated memory adress, but I don't understand two things:

1) Why does this happen with a dynamic array, and
2) Why does the error only happen when I try to put in a larger number.

Comment: Why not allocate the array after getting the size input?

Comment: For number 2, explain your code to your [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: For number 1: This does not really have anything to do with dynamic allocation. You just cannot access memory you don't own, doesn't matter *how* you violate that rule.

Comment: Because myArray is always 5 elements long, but you're trying to write the first 10 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Luke,
   You have defined the size of the array already. So it is not a dynamic array. It is a pointer to an array that has a size of 5 and can hence only store up to 5 ints.
2. So you basically have allocated enough space to hold 5 int. This means that if you try to store more than 5, for example the 6th int at index of 5, you are trying to access memory that is not yours to claim.
   for example here you have:

[] [] [] [] []

1  2  3  4  5

is good

[] [] [] [] []

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ...

cause the heap corruption.

Might I suggest std::vector ?

Comment: I didn't realize that I initialized the array before getting the user input, thanks.